# In Visual Studio 2013, can I jump to the usage of the object under the cursor by just one key?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

This question is about a C# project in Visual Studio 2013.

A lot of times, I have methods that are used only exactly ONCE. 
In other words, there's only one reference.

In that case, I'd like to navigate to where this function is called, by just pressing ONE keyboard shortcut.

I wasn't able to find a command for this.
Is this possible to achieve this with any extension?

Comment: It's 2022... I'm interested in this but it seems like it's still not available in VS.  In VS Code, if you hit Shift-F12 and there is only one reference it takes you directly there.

Comment: Just figured out: If I use "List View" in the references window it works a lot better.  I can do Shift+F12, then up/down arrows if there's more then one reference, then hit enter to go there... and the window will close by itself if set to auto-hide.  Only thing is for some reason it doesn't add that to my navigation history, like it does when I go to Definition.

Answer (score 1):

The **Edit.GoToReference** command navigates to the first reference call.

Comment: When I do this when the cursor is over the definition of a method, nothing happens unfortunately.

Comment: Looks like it works only for some C++ projects. My mistake proposing it for C#.

Comment: Ah, too bad :(   ---  I got excited for a moment :) Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>ctrl + K</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl + R</kbd> also does exactly what you need. You can assign your own shortcut for `Edit.FindAllReferences` command in Visual Studio Options - Environment - Keyboard.

Comment: This is close to the solution, but only goes half the way. I'm aware of this command. But what I'm looking for is a way to move the cursor to where the function is called, by just *one keyboard shortcut*.